# How does the linux perf tool get the miss rate of the l2 cache?

Tags: linux, cache, perf

I want to use perf tool to get the miss rate of l2 cache. I know how to get L1, and LLC.

```
perf stat -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores command

perf stat -e LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores,LLC-prefetches command
```

The above two commands can get the miss rate of `l1` and `llc`. But when I use `perf stat -e L2cache-loads, L2-cache-load-misses, L2-cache-stores command`, `an event syntax error:'L2-cache-loads'` error appears.

How do I get the miss rate of L2?

And when I use `perf stat -e L1-dcache-loads, L1-dcache-load-misses, L1-dcache-stores command` to get the miss rate of l1, the result is:

```
    19,405,514,800      L1-dcache-loads                                               (50.00%)
           956,038      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    0.00% of all L1-dcache hits    (66.67%)
     6,448,520,298      L1-dcache-stores                                              (66.67%)
           311,629      LLC-loads                                                     (66.67%)
           174,237      LLC-load-misses           #   55.91% of all LL-cache hits     (66.67%)
            72,755      LLC-stores                                                    (33.33%)
   <not supported>      LLC-prefetches

      54.586246766 seconds time elapsed
```

What do `0.0%, 55.91%` and `(50.00%), (66.67%), (66.67%), (66.67%), (66.67%), and (33.33%)` on the right represent?

Answer (score 2):

I think the relevant event is `l2_rqsts.all_demand_miss`. (`perf list` will show you all the available events.)

As to the percentages, 956,038 is 0.00% of 19,405,514,800, and 174,237 is 55.91% of 311,629 — *i.e.* 0% of L1 dcache loads were misses, and 55.91% of LLC dcache loads were misses. I don’t know about the percentages on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, l2_rqsts.all_demand_miss is effective. Can I specify how long it runs? Can I specify how long it runs? For example, 10 seconds, so I can compare in different situations.

Comment: If you want to run a system-wide `perf stat` for 10 seconds, the typical technique is `perf stat sleep 10`.

Comment: I want to measure the cache miss rate of my program in 10 seconds. This is convenient for comparison with other programs. I use perf stat sleep 1000 -e L1-dcache-loads command. An error will be displayed, how should I modify it? Thank you

Comment: `perf stat -e L1-dcache-loads sleep 10` will show the D1 cache loads over a 10-second period.

Comment: But I want to measure the L1 miss rate of my program. My program has been set to run on a certain core. How do I know the L1 cache miss rate of 10 seconds when my program runs on this core? thank you.

Comment: OK, so if you’ve pinned your program to a given core, you can use `perf stat`’s `-C` option to specify the CPUs to measure, along with the `-a` option (which I forgot from the previous examples).

Comment: But there is a problem here, that is, if the position of -a sleep is placed behind. It will be considered as part of my command. If it is put in front, it will report sleep: invalid option - e error.  for example perf stat -C 3 -a sleep 10  -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores command

Comment: The command you want to run must always come last, after all the `perf stat` options: `perf stat -a -C 3 -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores sleep 10`, and your command must be run in parallel, pinned to the corresponding CPU.

Comment: perf stat -a  -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores -C 3  sleep 10 command  When I put the command at the end, errors still occur. It will take my command as the parameter of sleep. An invalid time interval error occurred.

Comment: In `perf stat -a -C 3 -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores sleep 10`, the command to run is `sleep 10`. `perf stat -a -C 3 -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores sleep 10` is the *complete* command line to run the measurements for 10s. You need to run `command` *separately*, in parallel, pinned to the corresponding CPU.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you think sleep 10 is my command? No, I have a c file, such as hello.c, and I compile it into a hello executable file. I want to measure the cache miss rate for 10 seconds of hello execution. I think sleep 10 is for me to measure 10 seconds.

Comment: No, I don’t think `sleep 10` is your command. Running `perf` with `sleep 10` is how you get a measurement over 10s. It’s a bit of a “cheat”, and it means that the rest of `perf`’s measurements aren’t specific to the command you’re actually interested in. If you don’t mind killing your command, you could also run it with `perf stat ... timeout 10s command`.

Comment: You might know this already, but [Brendan Gregg’s `perf` page](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) provides a lot of examples which give a good feel for how to actually use `perf` in practice.

Comment: If I run my c program in a terminal. Then in another terminal, I knew its PID. I use perf stat -p PID -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores -C 3 -a sleep 10 Measure the cache miss rate of my c program running for 10 seconds. Is this correct?

Comment: You are so kind, thank you.

Comment: Ah, yes, `-p` is a better idea; you don’t need `-a -C 3` then.

Comment: the percentages in parentheses on the right must be the fraction of time the hardware counter was active, according to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678242/whats-the-meaning-of-cycles-annotation-in-perf-stat) that mentions [a patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/3/1/562) with a telltale comment