# Is there a way to monitor L1, L2 and L3 cache usage with command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, process

I'm looking for a way to know, using command line, how much CPU mem cache is using a running process... is there a way to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the linux perf tool get the miss rate of the l2 cache?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628193/how-does-the-linux-perf-tool-get-the-miss-rate-of-the-l2-cache) https://askubuntu.com/questions/650668/gui-for-monitoring-cpu-usage-including-l1-l2-caches-in-real-time

Comment: I'm going to give it a try... I've never used perf tool and don't know how it works but looks promising. Thanks!!